# Why is Spring Boot and MongoRepository findById(...) setting my integer keys to 0?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I currently have a MongoRepository with a REST interface that is performing basic CRUD. Everything works for the object, except for one `int` field. When I look at the object in Mongo itself, using `db.collection.find()`, I see the following representation:

```
{
    "_id" : "test1",
    "title" : "test1",
    "description" : "Adam's Api Root",
    "versions" : [
        "version 1",
        "version 2"
    ],
    "max_content_length" : 50000
}
```

Note `"max_content_length" : 50000`.

The following call is made to retrieve this object from the database:

```
ApiRootDocument apiRoot = apiRootsRepository.findById(id);
```

When my query is performed, and I look at my debugger, the object has all of the key-values set appropriately, except for `max_content_length`, which is set to 0, always.

The REST response looks like:

```
{
    "title": "test1",
    "description": "Adam's Api Root",
    "versions": [
        "version 1",
        "version 2"
    ],
    "max_content_length": 0
}
```

I am thinking this has something to do with variable naming, getters and setters, etc.

I'm using Gson for plain serialization/deserialization (though not custom conversion to/from Mongo), and the ApiRoot object declares the `max_content_length` field like so:

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("max_content_length")
private int maxContentLength;
```

I'm assuming the problem is related to the way I have the field declared, but I would like to avoid using Spring Data annotations on this field, as the objects are in a separate API.

What am I missing to get this 'int' field to read correctly?

Comment: Does it happen with all integer properties or just this one? I'm thinking it's probably the name. Can you try annotating the field with `@Field("max_content_length")`?

Answer (score 0):

Welp. I was doing something pretty silly. All of my updates are manual, and I was setting max_content_length, but the default mapping converter is looking for maxContentLength.